# What's the meaning of "a back-arching scream"?

Tags: meaning

I checked the phrase in some dictionaries but I didn't find it.

Could you please explain the phrase to me?

The full text is here:

The burn was the injury, I reasoned. It made sense to treat it first. I
fetched a pack of ice from the chest freezer on the patio, but when the pack
touched his leg **he screamed—a back-arching**, eye-popping scream that
made my brain claw at my skull.

Source: *Educated*: A Memoir by Tara Westover, 2018 p.73

Comment: You will not find every adjective formed by a noun and verb  in a dictionary: you need to search for arch (verb) + back part of the body), which becomes back-arching. Try that and then see if it makes sense. Other common ones: awe-inspiring work of art, for example. Also, eye-popping comes from pop and eyes.

Comment: "I checked the phrase in some dictionaries but I didn't find it." OK, but you should add what you did find. The meanings of the words themselves is pretty clear. "back-arching" is just something that makes your back arch. I'm looking for a specific language question here.

Comment: There's nothing special about this phrase.  As Lambie says, if you look up "arch" and "back", that's pretty much it.  As a metaphor for a *terrible* scream, it sounds a little weird to me, but writers do like to get creative.